# Convert Immutable java object to immutable object (Immutable or Builder)

Tags: dozer, mapper, orika

I want to convert one immutable object to another immutable objects. I googled and found that Dozzer and Orika are mostly used for object mappings.

I tried using Dozzer but seems that it doesn't work well with objects created using builder pattern.

```
Example:
//Source Object
public class EmployeeDTO{
private String id;
private String name;

private void setName(String name){this.name=name;}
private void setId(String id){this.id=id;}

public static class Builder{
public String id;
public String name;
public Builder setName(String name){this.name=name;}
public Builder setId(String id){this.id=id;}

public EmployeeDTO build(){
  EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = new EmployeeDTO();
employeeDTO.setName(this.name);
employeeDTO.setId(this.id);
return employeeDTO;
}
}
}

//Target Object
public class Employee{
private String id;
private String name;

private void setName(String name){this.name=name;}
private void setId(String id){this.id=id;}

public static class Builder{
public String id;
public String name;
public Builder setName(String name){this.name=name;}
public Builder setId(String id){this.id=id;}

public Employee build(){
  Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setName(this.name);
employee.setId(this.id);
return employee;
}
}
}
```

I want to convert these two structures interchangeably. I have little idea that I can create custommapper to perform this task. Please help me if it is possible with Dozzer/Orika in easy way.

Comment: The source and target objects have public fields and setters. How are they immutable then?

Comment: Thanks Adam for correcting me. I just coded it here so by mistake made fields/methods as public. corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

public class SourceObjectClass implements T{

```
private final String name;

private final int id;

public sourceObjectClass(final String name, final int id){

    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName(){

    return name;
}

public String getId(){

    return id;
}
```

}

//Destination Object

public class DestinationObjectClass implements T{

```
private final String name;

private final int id;


public sourceObjectClass(final String name, final int id){

    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName(){

    return name;
}

public String getId(){

    return id;
}
```

}

//Converter

//Converter

public class MyConverter{

```
public static T convert(SourceObjectClass sourceObject, Class<T> destinationClass){

    Class definition = Class.forName(destinationClass);

    return definition.newInstance(sourceObject.getName(),sourceObject.getId());
}
```

}

public class MyTestClass{

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    //Create an immutable object
    SourceClasssObject sourceObject = new SourceClassObject("Guest",100);

    //convert the above object into another immutable Object
    final DestinationObjectClass destination = MyConverter.convert(sourceObject,DestinationObjectClass.class);
}
```

}

Comment: Minor comment: 
Class definition = Class.forName(destinationClass.toString());

Anyhow I don't need it anymore and if someone has to do it in this way it will be pretty bad way to do it. It will be better to do manual conversion then. isn't it ?

Comment: You can generalize this logic using reflection so that you can get rid of calling getters.